# Hibernate filter not working with update query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In my application I have to use one filter condition (columnABC=:inputValue) for all SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries. Column 'columnABC' exist in all tables within application.

I have defined filter def in package-info file

```
@FilterDef(
        name = "columnFilter",
        parameters = @ParamDef(name = "columnABC", type = "int"),
        defaultCondition = "columnABC = :columnABC")
package com.example.entities;

import org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ParamDef;
```

Defined filter on entity

```
@Filter(name = "columnFilter")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "table1")
public class Entity1 implements Serializable {
----
---

    @Column(name = "columnABC")
    private Integer ColumnABC;
}

@Component
public class Repository1 {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

 public void setFilter(Integer columnABC) {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Filter filter = session.enableFilter("columnFilter");
        filter.setParameter("columnABC", columnABC);
    }
}
```

Filter is attached to session and it is getting appended for all findAll methods.For findById method it was not working so I have applied @Query and filter has attached to it.When I am running save statements filter is not getting attached to the query. What other option I can use to attach filter to update query.

```
@Service
public class Service1{

    @Autowired
    private Entity1Repository entity1Repository;
    
    ----
    ----

    entity1Repository.save(Entity1);
}   

 update
        table1 
    set
        column1=?,
        column2=?,
        column3=?,
        ---
    where
        column_id=?
```

Comment: Let's continue the discussion on Discourse: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-filter-not-working-with-update-query/7225/2

Comment: @priya I am also facing the same issue have you found any way to get it working?